# ExtJS: Display model in Ext.grid.property.Grid

Tags: extjs

I'd like to display the persistent fields (those defined in my model file) in a property grid.

[image]

**Property Grid:**

```
Ext.define('ATCOM.view.InspectorProperties', {
    extend : 'Ext.grid.property.Grid',
    alias : 'widget.inspectorProperties',
    cls : 'property-grid',
    height : 150,
    listeners : {
        beforerender : function() {
            // Rename the first column
            var cols = this.getView().getHeaderCt().getGridColumns();
            cols[0].setText("Property");
        },
        beforeedit : function(e) {
            // Read-only
            return false;
        }
    },
    source : {} // Start with no items
});
```

I load items like so in a select event (in a controller), where record is our model object and getInfo() is the property grid:

```
var source = {};
source.id = record.get('id');
source.start = record.get('start');
source.end = record.get('end');

this.getInfo().setSource(source);
```

**Model:**

```
Ext.define('ATCOM.model.Shift', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ 'id', {
        name : 'start',
        type : 'date',
    }, {
        name : 'end',
        type : 'date',
    }, 'position', 'controller' ],
    hasMany : {
        model : 'ATCOM.model.ShiftAlloc',
        name : 'allocations'
    }
});
```

Is there a better way to go about this so all non-associative fields (excluding `allocations` in my case) are automatically sent to the property grid? It might also be possible to read the fields with `ATCOM.model.Shift.getFields()` and iterate over those checking for `persistent:false;` to keep the remaining keys, but how do I get the class reference from an instance - as in, how do I get `ATCOM.model.Shift` from one of its instances so I can call getFields()?

EDIT:

For finding the class name: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Base-static-method-getName

Comment: +1 for your code that shows how to change the name of the column and how to make it read only...nice!

Comment: cheers, it takes some digging to find :\

Answer (score 1):

It may work to say setSource(record.data).  I am just playing with this now; it seems to show the right information, though you may lose control over the details of which fields to enable for editing, etc.

Comment: Yeah, the only problem here is that it may show more information than is needed in `data`, such as the CSS class, parent IDs etc.